# export bash variable through HTML form method

Tags: html, bash, shell, cgi

Can someone please help me to know how to do this:

script1: "xx.sh" has these lines below

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
tr=$(mktemp -d)
trr=$(echo $tr | awk '{split($0,array,"/")} END{print array[3]}')
pud=$(echo "$trr" | awk '{split($0,array,".")} END{print array[2]}')
mkdir $pud
echo -e "123" > file
mv file $pud/    #(briefly, I want to use this "file" in the script "yy.sh" for some other analysis. This is a webserver script snippet, based on my program, there could be many instances running at one time, hence "pud" has to be unique, and the "file" is unique for every instance too)

echo "<html>"
echo "<head>"
echo "</head>"
echo "<body>" 
echo "<form action=\"yy.sh\" method=\"GET\">"
echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Click me to get the results page.\">"
echo "</form>"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"
```

What I want to do is get the value of variable "pud" in the second bash script "yy.sh" ("yy.sh" is in the same parent directory as "xx.sh"). Can someone please help me know how to do this?

Thanks much!

Comment: What's your desired output ?

Comment: I have edited the script, please have a look and let me know how this could be done. Thanks! If something is not clear, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I see , you need a uniquifier to save the file in an unique dir for each instance so that your yy.sh can iterate over all of these directories.

You can try this :

```
dir="${pud}_`date +%s%N`" `date +%s%N` : will give you time in seconds and NanoSeconds since the epoch.
mkdir "${dir}"
echo -e "123" > file
mv file $dir/

# Pass this file path  to yy.sh as following
sh yy.sh "${dir}/file"
```

In your `yy.sh`
Use `$1` to refer the file path passed by `xx.sh`. `$1` means first command line parameter, `$2` would means second and so on ..

Eg.

```
#yy.sh
echo "Hello World" >> "$1"  #This will append "hello world" to file whose path was passed by xx.sh
```

Comment: Thanks! but, to make it clear, "yy.sh" is called for every instance, so,  the unique directory made in one instance has to be looked for the "file" in every instance. That is why, I need to somehow make "yy.sh" look for the specific "${dir}". Can you please tell me how can I pass the value of "${dir}" to "yy.sh"? Or if you have any other way to do this please let me know. Thanks

Comment: correction in previous comment - "so, the unique directory made in one instance has to be looked for the "file" in **that** instance"

Comment: Thanks :-) , but, doing "`sh yy.sh "${dir}/file`" executes "yy.sh" in "xx.sh". I would like to do it using HTML form as in my script above, i.e when the button is clicked then "yy.sh" executes and the value of "`${dir}/file`" is present in "yy.sh". Is there a way to do it without executing "yy.sh" in "xx.sh". Please let me know if am not clear. Thanks much!